# bundle nltk_data with pyinstaller

Tags: python, nltk, executable, pyinstaller

This is somewhat of a similar question that I've previously had.
Trying to figure out a way to publish an executable without the client needing `nltk_data` libraries.
Current directory tree looks like this:

```
.
+-- Include
+-- Lib
+-- Scripts
+-- Src
|    +-- mainservice.py  << flask service
|    +-- mainprogram.py  << nltk_data logic
```

The issue is that I can't seem to add nltk_data as a hidden import. The executable builds fine but when the client runs my executable it states that it needs `nltk_data` to run.

My current pyinstaller command is:

```
'pyinstaller --hidden-import=flask --onefile -d -y ' + pwd + '/src/semantic_service.py'
```

I've tried several variations to try to include `nltk_data` as a hidden import and `nltk` and haven't had much luck either.
So far I've referred to this link https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1099 to try to find resolves with not much luck.

Is it possible to create `nltk_data` as a hidden import, or would the client just always need a copy of this library? If there is a hook solution, could someone help point me to try right direction?